# Html5 input pattern check

Tags: html, regex

i'm not good in html pattern validation.

I have this problem, my input text is valid only : min 3 max 30 chars,
white space at first and at end of the string is not allowed, is allowed white space between one word and another is allowed, is allowed A-Za-z, first char of word it must be Uppercase and the others word it must be Lowercase.
Thanks.

--UPDATE--
input#name

Valid Examples:

- 'Mario Giovanni'
- 'Maria'
- 'Jacopo Karol Pio'
- 'Jacopo K'

Invalid Examples:

- ' Mario Giovanni'
- 'Mario Giovanni '
- ' Mario Giovanni '
- 'Mario   Giovanni'
- 'maria'
- 'mAria'
- 'Antonio mario'

Comment: What have you tried? It's also hard to follow your rules, could you maybe insert a list into your question to better define them? Present examples of what to and what not to match.

Comment: Simplistically `^(?=.{3,30)[A-Z](?:\s?[a-z])+$`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a Regular Expression pattern to check whether the input is valid or not, as well as the `maxlength` and `minlength` attributes to ensure that the input is between 3 and 30 characters.

Regarding the RegEx pattern, we must:

- Start at the beginning of the input: `^`
- Verify that the first character is between A and Z: `[A-Z]`
- Verify that the following characters before the last one are lowercase letters or spaces: `[a-z ]*`, where `*` indicates that there might be multiple characters matching that part of the pattern; if you only want to allow one space between word, then use `([a-z]* ?)`
- Verify that the last character is a lowercase letter: `[a-z]$`, where `$` indicates the end of the input

Below is the code I would use.

```html
<input type="text" minlength=3 maxlength=30 pattern="^[A-Z][a-z ]*[a-z]$">
```

Comment: This would allow for multiple spaces in between words

Comment: It was quite unclear to me whether the OP only wanted one whitespace character to be allowed between words or multiple, but I completely agree with your point and will provide and alternative pattern in case they only want to allow one.

Comment: OP's request is certainly cryptic but I read "white space between one word and another is allowed" to mean that there should be no consecutive whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you all, forgive me for my bad English.
One white space between words.

Answer (score 0):

If you need pure regex then this should work for you:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(?=^.{3,30}$)^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [a-z]+)*$">
```

- `(?=^.{3,30}$)` - use a positive lookahead to make sure we have between 3 and 30 chars
- `^[A-Z]` - require start with a capital letter
- `[a-z]*` - optionally allow lowercase letters to follow
- `(?: [a-z]+)*` - optionally allow a repeating group of a space char follow by one or more letters
- `$` - end of string anchor

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you wait is:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?=^.{3,30}$)^[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*$">
```

Notice this is being validated in the user browser, and doesn't configure a secure input validation. You should check the input again at server-side before using it anywhere.